# How to create a Django REST Framework View instance from a ViewSet class?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to ***unit*** test Django REST Framework view set permissions for two reasons: speed and simplicity. In keeping with these goals I would also like to avoid using any mocking frameworks. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
request = APIRequestFactory().post(…)
view = MyViewSet.as_view(actions={"post": "create"})
self.assertTrue(MyPermission().has_permission(request, view))
```

The problem with this approach is that `view` is not actually a `View` instance but rather a *function* which does something with a `View` instance, and it does not have certain properties which I use in `has_permission`, such as `action`. How do I construct the kind of `View` instance which can be passed to `has_permission`?

The permission is already tested at both the integration and acceptance level, but I would like to avoid creating several complex and time-consuming tests to simply check that each of the relevant actions are protected.

---

I've been able to work around this by monkeypatching a view set instance and manually dispatching it:

```
view_set = MyViewSet()
view_set.action_map = {"post": "create"}
view_set.dispatch(request)
```

Comment: share your `viewset` code and `permission` code

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like below.

```
request = APIRequestFactory().post(…)
view_obj = MyViewSet()
self.assertTrue(MyPermission().has_permission(request, view_obj))
```

Comment: No, I made it perfectly clear that I want to run *unit* tests.

Comment: Of course, as soon as you provide a solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: Nope, `view_obj` is a `Response` object, not a `View`. I've already tried this. Have a look in DRF's viewsets.py if you don't believe me.

Comment: Still nope. This suggestion is equivalent to just removing my workaround, which gets us back to the original "AttributeError: 'MyViewSet' object has no attribute 'action'" issue.

Comment: You have to add required attributes manually. Because there is no other way to get view object. To confirm it please check Django rest GitHub repository.